# How to upload multiple files from two file upload controls MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am in between one weird problem, I have two file controls on a single page using MVC. I am getting all files by using Request.Files but I want to differentiate between these two controls. I want seperate Brochure Images & different Media Images. Currently, I'm doing like this

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 1 && Request.Files[1].ContentLength != 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        string CurrentFileName = Request.Files[i].FileName;
    }
}
```

I have used something like above code, Now I want different images as it's uploaded.

Comment: Give each file input a `name` attribute and add paramaters for those in your POST method - `(HttpPostedFileBase file1, HttpPostedFileBase file2)` (or `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` if the input is `multiple`)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, But How I can upload multiple Images in 1st Control. I tried using IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> or HttpPostedFileBase[]. But It is adding duplcate images. Let's say If I added 2 images , I am getting counter of 4.

Comment: Have you given each file input a different name attribute (and matched those with the parameter names)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an action with the matching parameters:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase broacherupload, 
HttpPostedFileBase mediaupload) { }
```

For the multiple:

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> broacherupload, 
IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> mediaupload) { }
```

Comment: Not sure, why I'm getting duplicate images. using IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> broacherupload , I uploaded 2 images but in broacherupload , I'm getting 4 images

Comment: Post your full code please. Including razor design and controller

Comment: Tried like this  `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Image, HttpPostedFileBase BrouchersLink`   in Controller and `<input type="file" id="uploadConditionImage" accept=".jpg,.png,.JPG,.jpeg,.JPEG,.PNG,.gif,.GIF" name="Image" title="Image" multiple="multiple" />` in View

Comment: as I said add your code, you may be doing something wrong.